# SOCKETS EM C - Número de Sequência TCP

Tags: c, tcp

Estou precisando de um help com `sockets` em C. Minha professora passou um trabalho em que devo executar a comunicação `TCP` entre cliente e servidor onde eu devo executar algumas regras..

- 1 - O Cliente envia uma mensagem ao servidor. A mensagem deve conter
  o número de sequência e a quantidade de bytes carregada pela
  mensagem.
- 2 - O servidor deve receber a mensagem e enviar um reconhecimento ao
  cliente. A mensagem de reconhecimento deve conter, o número de
  sequência da mensagem reconhecimento, o número de sequência do
  próximo segmento a ser enviado pelo cliente.

Alguém conseguiria me explicar melhor como funciona o numero de sequencia e se possível me auxiliar a codificar isso? A parte da comunicação TCP entre cliente/servidor está em anexo e pronta.

Trecho de código cliente:

```
 sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected\n");

    //keep communicating with server
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter message : ");
    gets(message);
    fflush(stdin);
        //scanf("%s" , message);

        //Send some data
        if( send(sock , message, strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("Send failed");
            return 1;
        }

        //Receive a reply from the server
        if( recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("recv failed");
            break;
        }

        puts("Server reply :");
        //puts(server_reply);
    int vl = 0;
    for(int i =0; server_reply[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        if(server_reply[i] != ' ')
            vl += (int)server_reply[i];
    }
        printf("%d\n",vl);
}
    close(sock);
```

Trecho de código do servidor:

```
//Create socket
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (socket_desc == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}
puts("Socket created");

//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

//Bind
if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    //print the error message
    perror("bind failed. Error");
    return 1;
}
puts("bind done");

//Listen
listen(socket_desc , 3);

//Accept and incoming connection
puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

//accept connection from an incoming client
client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
if (client_sock < 0)
{
    perror("accept failed");
    return 1;
}
puts("Connection accepted");

//Receive a message from client
while( (read_size = recv(client_sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
{
    //Send the message back to client
    write(client_sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));
}

if(read_size == 0)
{
    puts("Client disconnected");
    fflush(stdout);
}
else if(read_size == -1)
{
    perror("recv failed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Monte as mensagens a serem enviadas ao servidor seguindo o layout solicitado, contendo o número de sequência e o tamanho da área de dados da mensagem.

Por exemplo:

mensagem 1:

```
0000 0010 0123456890
```

A mensagem 1 tem o número de sequência 0 (0000), o tamanho 10 (0010), e 10 bytes de dados: 01...90

mensagem 2:

```
0001 0015 012345689012345
```

A mensagem 2 tem o número de sequência 1 (0001), o tamanho 15 (0015), e 15 bytes de dados: 01...9012345

Etc.

A resposta do servidor vai conter apenas o último número de sequência recebido e o próximo número de sequência a ser recebido.

Fluxo de mensagens:

Cliente envia mensage 0000:

```
0000 0010 0123456890
```

Servidor responde resposta 0000:

```
0000 0001
```

nesta mensagem o servidor informa ao cliente que recebeu a mensagem com número de sequência 0000, e espera receber a próxima mensagem com número de sequência 0001.

Etc.